# Why does WebStorm's LiveEdit not work in Chrome?

Tags: debugging, webstorm, liveedit

I am exploring WebStorm's trial version and would like to use the LiveEdit features.

I am not able to use the LiveEdit features after performing the following actions:

1. Made sure that LiveEdit is turned on
2. Installed the Chrome extension
3. Restarted the browser after installing the extension (I still suspect it is not required)
4. Run the HTML page in chrome

When I modify the HTML body, I don't see the changes reflected in Chrome.

I read on a forum that netty is not required.

Do we need it?

What else do I need to configure so that I can use the LiveEdit feature?

PS: I am using WebStorm 5.0.

Comment: See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/LiveEdit and http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5471059.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you happen to have IntelliJ open by chance? 
The point is that the port, 63342, is 'seized' by another app (even if it has nothing to do with HTML debugging).

When the port is busy, LiveEdit tries the next one, 63343. If you right click the JB icon on Chrome, choose Options, increment the port by one, and press Apply, you will magically connect. I wish Jetbrains would have bothered to inform the user what is the port that they are currently attempting to use.

In my PC it happened when I had Mac on. Either one of the following worked:
1. Kill IntelliJ IDEA (that was also open) and try again
2. Increment the port by one as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, bumping up port number in JB's chrome plugin fixed my problem.

Comment: If you use a different port than the default IDE ones (63342, 63343), it won't change by itself.

Comment: In my case (Arch), 63343 was seized by another IDE and 63342 worked. Well, that's weird but thanks for the tips

Comment: What if i need the intellij idea open during live edit? How can I do both?

Answer (score 14):

I had to go to Run -> Debug (CTRL+F5 on Windows)

Answer (score 4):

What helped in my case was activating "Can accept external connections" under the Settings -> Build, Execute, Deployment -> Debugger

[WebStorm Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdzcI.png)

---

More details as requested:

1. Installed the JetBrains IDE Extension for Chrome
2. Make sure the LiveEdit Plugin is installed and activated (Settings -> Plugins)
3. Make sure "Can accept external connections" is checked (Settings -> Build, Execute, Deployment -> Debugger) **AND** Port is the same as in the Chrome Extension
4. Make sure Update ist set to "Auto in (ms)" e.g. 300 (Settings -> Build, Execute, Deployment -> Debugger -> Live Edit)

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Updated the original post with more details

Comment: Also remember to remove your defined server from "Settings -> Build, Execute, Deployment".

Answer (score 3):

In my case **live edit** was just disabled (for some reason)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone googling this thread, LiveEdit is now supported without a plugin.  Just go into settings and uncheck "Use JetBrains IDE Support extension for debugging and Live Edit".

Without the extension, the debugging and live edit are more reliable based on my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make Chrome and Webstorm to link with each other. Chrome plugin was set to 63343 port or something like that.
I am on Windows. I opened command line with administrator privileges and typed:

```
netstat -a -b
```

to see all programs and ports they are listening to. I then found first entry regarding WebStorm.exe and saw that it was listening on port 30897. I set that port number in my chrome plugin options, and everything worked.

[image]

Comment: this really helped narrow it down. Like you said, my phpstorm was running in 63343 when the actual port it was listening on was 1 less, 63342

Comment: This still works; it's good info. On the other hand, this routine takes a while. My firewall has this same information immediately available.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix: in the Chrome addon configuration, use the ip `0.0.0.0` for the host.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the automatic connection configuration from Internet Explorer properties worked for me smoothly. IE is the boss.