# Live Edit using Webstorm 9.0

Tags: javascript, webstorm, liveedit

I have went through this link https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Live+Edit as well as this question thread [Webstorm LiveEdit for chrome not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069520/webstorm-liveedit-for-chrome-not-working) and I still cannot get my Webstorm live edit to work.

I have the live edit plugin enabled, the auto reload setting on (300ms) and the jetbrains chrome extension installed. When I activate debug mode the project opens up fine in the browser but the page does not actively reload when I adjust the content or save the file. One thing I have noticed (and the above links recommend) is to make sure that Live Edit is clicked in the view menu dropdown but I do not have that option in regular run or debug mode.

Any idea how I can get this to work properly? If you need more information to solve this issue please let me know.

Comment: *"is to make sure that Live Edit is clicked in the view menu dropdown but I do not have that option in regular run or debug mode."* That's was the case in previous versions -- in current versions this option is no longer available as whole LiveEdit approach was redesigned. Please refer to http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same problem but one alternative if you need live edit is:

Try right click on the html file (suppose index.html) and then choose the option debug index.html. Then this will generate an option at the top. So every time you click on the bug icon it will open Chrome and every change that you make on index.html will appear immediately on Chrome.

Also if you select some code in WebStorm it will appear in yellow on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. I'm utilizing WebStorm 2016.2.2. In addition the extension for chrome did want to connect. The following steps solved my issue:

Verify that your configuration in your IDE matched with the extension in your browser.

[image]

[image]

Copy the URL path up to 63342. Now lets go to the browser. Right click the JB extension icon.

[image]

Make sure that your extension set up matches IDE configuration like so.

[image]

Hope this helps for newer versions of WS!!!